# Reading url from database not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have some urls for a pdf that I want to read from the database. But when I try to echo the result of my query, I get no result at all.

I'm trying to read the data with the following code:

(artikeldb.php)

```
//  content
$attachment             = "SELECT * FROM `site_attachments` WHERE parent_id = '".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']."' ";
$attachmentcon          = $conn->query($attachment);
$attachmentcr           = array();
while ($attachmentcr[]  = $attachmentcon->fetch_array());
```

This is where I want to read the results.

(content.php)

```
$pdf = $attachmentcr[0]['url'];

echo $attachmentcr[0]['url'];
echo $pdf;
```

But neither of those echoes work.

I want to read the url that belongs to the correct article (using `parent_id` , which is the same as `id` in site_content).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to print `$attachmentcr`  and post the result here....

Comment: print_r($attachmentcr); please

Comment: That shows: `Array ( [0] => ) ` So the array is empty. But I am sure the table exist and has a row called `url`

Comment: So it has something to do with this part: `'".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']."'` Because when I add a number, for example 16, it shows the correct array data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `var_dump($attachmentcon = $conn->query($attachment))`?
What is returned after the query?

Comment: This shows: `object(mysqli_result)#9 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(26) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: `["num_rows"]=> int(0)` means your qurey succeded (not failed) but you have no rows matching to the query

Comment: @xmike Alright. But if I add a normal parent_id like: `16` in the query instead of `'".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']."'` it shows the correct query. So something is wrong in the query.

Comment: I would suggest trying `print_r` or `var_dump` the `$attachment` before quering and look at it. May be there is something you unexpected or unintended? btw, `parent_id` field in the table is integer or varchar? Number or string?

Comment: looks like you just need to remove single quotes, db engine treats `parent_id` as a string.

Comment: It's a varchar. Printing $attachment shows: `SELECT * FROM `site_attachments` WHERE parent_id = '' `

Comment: I mean `"SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE parent_id = ".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']` instead of `"SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE parent_id = '".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']."' "`

Comment: @xmike This: `$attachment     = "SELECT * FROM snm_attachments WHERE parent_id = ".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']." ";` Gives me the following error: `There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]`

Comment: still I think its integer-typed since your hardcoded replacement for 16 works. You can check via `SHOW FIELDS FROM \`site_attachments\``

Comment: Yeah it's weird. I don't know what's wrong in my formatting? Without the single quotes the query doesn't run at all. This is the result of the fields btw: https://i.gyazo.com/d1e8c9827aa9a4385112f323fce9e430.png

Comment: try to remove `." "` from the end of the qurey (although should not be the deal). And what shows `var_dump` the `$attachment` after such query construction? As far as I understand it should be `SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE parent_id = 16`

Comment: my guess was correct: `parent_id` is a numeric type so it should go without  quotes. And was this a typo: `snm_attachments` ?

Comment: Yeah, forget about that :P. But without quotes the query doesn't even run. I can't var dump because I only see the sql syntax error.

Comment: anyway if you make the query look like `SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE parent_id=16` it (almost) must work.

Comment: `var_dump` should be placed before `$attachmentcon          = $conn->query($attachment);` and btw also suggest use `\`parent_id\`` instead of `parent_id`. So the final query to be `SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE \`parent_id\`=16`

Comment: This shows the following result: `string(55) "SELECT * FROM site_attachments WHERE parent_id = '' " Array ( [0] => ) `

Comment: `$attachment = "SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE \`parent_id\`=".$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id'];` if you use this construction does it form `SELECT * FROM \`site_attachments\` WHERE \`parent_id\`=16`?

Comment: ok.. so there is no value in `$attachmentcr[0]['parent_id']` )))

Comment: make your code to place the value into it and it should be ok after that

Comment: Yeah I got it to work. I used another query which gets the article ID and just echoed the id value instead of the parent id from the same table.